# Trouble with loading a tree structure in django models

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have 2 django models like this

```
class Thread(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)

class Post(models.Model):

    message = models.TextField(blank=True)
    thread = models.ForeignKey(Thread, related_name='posts')
    depth = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    reply_to = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, related_name='replies',
            blank=True)
```

I noticed that when i do this

```
roots = Thread.posts.filter(depth=0)
for post in roots:
   replies = post.replies
```

django execute a query to get all the roots then it executes new queries to get the children of a specific post, I know i will be working with all the posts in a specific thread.

I want to know if there is a way to make django load all the posts with one query and I could also use the model's relation to get all the children recursively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not built-in to django, but you can use apps like treebeard or django-mptt for this.

https://tabo.pe/projects/django-treebeard/

https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get all posts related to a particular thread then you can do something like:

```
posts = Post.objects.filter(thread=thethread)
```

where 'thethread' is the Thread object you are interested in.  It might also be useful to sort it on reply_to and depth so that it is returned in an order that is easy to walk the tree in the correct order:

```
posts = Post.objects.filter(thread=thethread).order_by('reply_to', 'depth')
```

tuxacanfly's suggestion of django-treebeard and django-mptt is useful for reducing database queries when working with hierarchical data in SQL and would be good options if you need more flexibility then just returning all the posts for a particular thread.

It looks from the data-structure that you are doing this for a forum or comment system - a good article on this is http://www.sqlteam.com/article/sql-for-threaded-discussion-forums which has a django implementation at https://github.com/danirus/django-comments-xtd